# Why does this simple code not work (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)

Tags: c#, list, while-loop

```
int i = 0;
int x = 10;
List<int> group = new List<int>();

while (i < x)
{
    RichTextBoxShowTafel.AppendText(Convert.ToString(group[i]));
    i++;
}
```

Why does this not work? I want to display the first 10 numbers of the List called: "group".

edit:
I actually want to create variables and print it in a row...

Comment: well.. group is empty...

Comment: What, exactly, do you _expect_ this code to do?

Comment: I want to create variables and print it in a row...

Comment: What do you mean you want to create variables? Do you just want to print 0-10? Or do you actually want to create variables? Whatever that means...

Comment: But I can't.... I really wish to do it...

Comment: By creating variable I mean for example: 1, 2 ,3 ,4 ,5 that there will be for every number an unique variable declared, so if there is 1032 numbers, there must be for each number an unique variable, I can't declare them manually...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You never put anything in the group variable. You only instantiated an empty list.

And you'd be better off doing this:

```
foreach (int item in group)
{
  RichTextBoxShowTafel.AppendText(item.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because group is empty? As it has no elements, you can't access group[0], which is what you do in the first iteration

Answer (score 1):

This is because `group` is empty!

When your loop first executes then `i = 0` then you try `Convert.ToString(groups[i])` which will always fail as there is no index of `0` in `group`

Answer (score 1):

You should add elements in the list before you try to get them. The is the reason you got ArgumentOutOfRangeException. You can avoid the exception by adding element first.

```
    int i = 0;
    int x = 10;
    List<int> group = new List<int>();

    while (i < x)
    {
        group.Add(i);
        RichTextBoxShowTafel.AppendText(Convert.ToString(group[i]));
        i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting `group` to be populated with numbers, you will have to do that yourself. Declaring and initializing it `List<int> group = new List<int>();` only creates it. There is nothing inside. If you want to try putting variables in you can do something like this:

```
for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
{
   group.Add(j);
}
```

Comment: This is more what I needed! Thanks!

Comment: Another way is to do `var group = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).ToList()`. Maybe you could even omit the `.ToList()` part if it is not essential that group be a `List<>`. Use `foreach` on `group`.